# How to clear the existing list data values

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding

I would like to know how to delete(clear) the existing list data values before binding new values.

I'm using the list for binding data dynamically using http services. When I make a new call to the service, I want the exiting items to be flushed and bind the newly retrieved data to the same list. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly set the dataProvider to null, or you can use removeAll() on the dataProvider.

Answer (score 0):

You need not clear the data if you are binding `httpService.lastResult` to `list.dataProvider`. The data binding will create a new `ListCollectionView` object (`ArrayCollection` or `XMLListCollection` as the case may be) and assign it to `list.dataProvider`. Old data will be cleared automatically.